# QGIS- Categorized symbol styling

Tags: symbology, qgis-2.12

I work with this polygon shapefile:

[image]

[image]
[image]

I can see the values 0,1 color but I can't see where the purple polygon location. In the attribute table there no more than two values, so I don't understand why the purple polygon added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purple color is assigned to a polygon that has a NULL value under the Field DN OR has a value but not 0 or 1. For example, if you assign a value of 2 to a polygon, it will have a purple color. So in your case, if all the polygons have 0 or 1 values, the purple color has no effect, and you can check it out if you don't want to show it in the legend.

In the following image I have categorized my legend based on Jp field from 1 - 5, but also has a green color in the legend which is not shown in the map.

[image]

When I change the value of the first row of Jp field to Null I got the green color.

[image]

Also, when I change the value of the first row of Jp field to 7 I got the green color.

[image]